# Bad artifact when bevelling smooth mesh

Tags: bevel

Is there any way to do a bevel similar to that on my screenshot without the artifact (the square appearing) with smooth shading? I see the result is due to all the vertices on the face created by the bevel, but I don't know the best way to solve this. All help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your object low-poly, if you smooth it it will try to smooth the 90° angles and it will give what you see. A trick is to use *Auto-Smooth*, i.e. ask Blender to only smooth the lower angles: Select your object in *Object* mode, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Shading Smooth*, then go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* Data > *Normals*, enable *Auto-Smooth* and keep a low angle like for example 30°.

[image]

Note that the general shape will stay angular, if you don't want that you'll need to give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and add some edge loops to sharp the angles.

[image]

Comment: I didn't manage to get the result in your last screenshot. I used the subsurf modifier and added some edge loops, but I still get the angular shape.

Comment: mmmh weird, maybe make sure that you have a Subdivision value of 2 in the modifier?

Comment: what are you talking about when you talk about the angular shape? I was talking about the beveled round angle

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I uploaded a new wireframe of the mesh in my post above.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, what I meant is, to smooth your object, you can either choose the Auto-Smooth trick or the Subsurf modifier, it's your choice. It doesn't seem like you have tried any of these solutions

Comment: Ah! I understand. Reason I'm using smooth shading, is because I'm importing it into Substance Painter and can't have flat faces. But how did you get all the edges to go from the bevel to only one vertex? Did you do that manually after applying the bevel?

Comment: This is a question about topology... once you've created your bevel, use the knife to create edge loops, use J to join vertices, etc... you need to have a clean topology, particularly no ngons

Comment: Yes. The ngon was the reason. I wasn't sure whether or not I had to clean the topology after bevels, but I see now that it's necessary.